# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask', What did I do wrong?

Tags: python, flask, module, windows-10, installation

I'm more or less new to computer science and can not even manage to run my first "Hello World" in Flask (Python 3; on my Windows-10 computer). I have tried some different tutorials on how to get started with Flask but did not find them really helpful so I did not finish them. Eventually I found a tutorial that seemed comprehensive and fitting my needs, but Visual Studio Code Terminal could not execute my code but gave me back an Error Message. Maybe I created a global virtual environment before I started this course that I'm following along now, and that's why it gives me that Error, but am not sure.

So this is the tutorial that I eventually picked and am currently following along: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QjtW-wnXlUY. 
The tutorial showed me how to set up and activate a local virtual environment in my project folder and pip install Flask as well as save app.py, with the help of my command batch and VSCode.

Then the user should try and run the following code (see below this paragraph). On my browser it really worked perfectly fine, but the Visual Studio Code-Terminal gave me an error message called "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'" (I know there are some similar-named threads out there in stackoverflow, but the answers given did not help me with my problem and also it seems to me that my case is slightly different). So this is the code I tried to run in Visual Studio Code:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Hello world!"
```

And this is the complete ErrorMessage that Visual Studio Code-Terminal gave me:

```
PS C:\Program Files\DB Browser for SQLite> & C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/python.exe c:/Users/User/Desktop/Flask_app/app.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/User/Desktop/Flask_app/app.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'**
PS C:\Program Files\DB Browser for SQLite>
```

Any ideas what's wrong with my code? Maybe it has to do with the path I stored it in? I got no idea; am very thankful for help!

Cheers.

Comment: if u had installed via ```pip```, do a ```pip freeze``` & check if flask is installed & to install type ```pip install flask```.

Comment: Hi @Sushanth , thanks for your advice! Normally Flask must be pip installed but maybe something went wrong so I am going to try pip freeze out. Just one last question before I do this: How can I un-freeze after having checked out my flask-installation? Simply type "pip un-freeze" or what should I do?

Comment: ```pip freeze``` is not going to cause any harm, that's the pip command to list installed modules and fyi, there is nothing just called un-freeze

Comment: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_freeze/

Comment: ok. I'm an idiot X) Thanks! ... By the way: Result was: Flask is installed. ... pity ... could have been so easy.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the virtual environment you created is activated before running the app. 
Also make sure it is activated when you run 'pip install flask'.

Comment: Hi healthy_meerkat, my venv was activated before i pip installed flask and before running the app. I will edit my post a bit so that this is made clear.

Answer (score 0):

first install the flask in your system

```
pip install flask
```

run the flask server then try it

```
> set FLASK_APP=hello
> flask run
```